# Category which has no non-trivial adjoint functors

Tags: ct.category-theory, adjoint-functors

Does there exist a category C which such that there is no functor $F:C \rightarrow D$ with $D\not\cong C$ which has a left (or right) adjoint?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The empty category trivially satisfies this (there are no functors at all from a nonempty category to the empty category), but no other such category exists.  Let $A$ be any category with a terminal object $1$, and consider the projection $C\times A \to C$.  This has a right adjoint $C\to C\times A$ given by $c\mapsto (c,1)$.  However, these functors are not equivalences unless $C$ is empty or $A$ is equivalent to the terminal category (and more generally if $C$ is small (or even accessible) it is easy to find an $A$ such that $C\times A$ cannot be equivalent to $C$ by any functor).

Comment: However, if $C$ is empty, then $C \times A \cong C$.

Comment: Oh, you're right!  In fact, the empty category is obviously an example; I'll edit that in.

Comment: Here I am assuming that by "$D\not\cong C$" you really mean that the adjunction in question is not an equivalence, which seems to me like the most natural question to ask.  If you really mean to ask whether there exists *any* equivalence between $C$ and $D$ and want to ask about large categories with no restrictions whatsoever, the question seems like it might be rather delicate set-theoretically.

Comment: @EricWofsey, I don't think there are any reasonable set-theoretic issues. If you recall that (any) set theory is closed under set-theoretic operations, then it'll be obvious, that due to cardinality reasons, you may always find such $A$.

Comment: How do you find such an $A$ if $C$ is large?

Comment: If your concept of "large" is closed under power-objects, then in exactly the same way as for "small" categories.

Comment: I have never heard of a concept of "large" being closed under power sets.

Comment: @EricWofsey, this is the only reasonable concept for studying internal categories. On the other hand, I have never heard of any useful mathematical results concerning "large" categories, when you assume that the concept of "large" is not set-theoretic.

Comment: @MichalR.Przybylek, I don't understand what you mean.  Usually in my experience when studying internal categories, the corresponding notion of "large category" is an indexed category or fibration, and those may or may not be closed under power sets depending on whether the ambient notion of "large category" is so.  And all of "basic" category theory works fine for large categories if "large" means a proper class in ZFC or NBG, and those don't have powersets.

Comment: @MikeShulman, Its not about the category of fibrations being closed under power objects (which is, of course, not), but about the category of discrete fibrations --- i.e. the question is whether $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathbb{C}^{op}}$ is closed under power objects, or not. This question, on the other hand, depends on the notion of $\mathbf{Set}$ and the size of $\mathbb{C}$, and is (almost) completely independent of the status of your meta-classes (i.e. whether they are closed under power-objects or not). (cont)

Comment: But, what I really meant, is that when $\mathbb{C}$ is a $\mathbf{Set}$-internal category, then the category of large $\mathbb{C}$-internal sets is always closed under power objects.
BTW, There is no concept like a "class" in ZFC (in contrast to NBG), so you have to formalize somehow what you mean. In my experience, when it comes to category theory, every formalization of the concept of class that does not satisfy the reflection principle does more harm than good, and only confuses people.

Comment: @MichalR.Przybylek, this is getting rather off-topic, maybe we should continue it elsewhere.